# JQuery FullCalender: set two different background colors for different types of events

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, fullcalendar

I am using jquery plugin fullcalendar for my project and I have two types of events. One is events and one is classes. The calendar looks fine on desktop view but it looks confused on mobile view.

I want if any class on specific date then background color should be different and when there is any event then background color should be different and if both are on that date then background color should be mixture of both colors.

When I click on that event or class then a div should append with the details of that event/class. Is it possible in full calendar? Please suggest.

Comment: You can add a  `classNames` property to each event https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object, then use css for background

Comment: Yes, all of that is possible. What have you researched? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Where is your code?